# Audio effect: tune to a particular frequency

Tags: audio, plug-ins, autotune

What software configuration or VST do you recommend for taking a realtime audio feed and "tune" it to a particular frequency (note)?

Answer (score 2):

Antares invented the [Auto-Tune](http://www.antarestech.com/products/auto-tune-evo.shtml), which is I think what you are asking for. They do a plug-in for Evo, but generally people use the full application.

It can gently or aggressively pitch shift an input note to the closest "correct" note.

[This Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-Tune) article gives some background, and some example audio clips.

Comment: Can you recommend a specific software or VST "receipe" to achieve the objective?

Comment: Yes - the one I linked to in my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest looking at Celemony's Melodyne. I haven't used Auto-Tune for a long time, but Melodyne killed it in the water for me. Notably, when Polyphonic tuning came in. They may be closer now than before. Research!

If you just need a rough match, a lot of DAWs and audio-in synth (FX etc.) have pitch transpose / adjustment. However, the two aforementioned plugins will allow you to tighten the fluctuations in pitch.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say which DAW you are using, but as you mention VST if you are using Steinberg then for real-time operation there is a plug-in that comes with the DAW called PitchCorrect and for non-realtime you have the VeriAudio engine.